# Перевод координат LatLng(долгота, широта) в прямоугольную систему координат(метры.)

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, android-library

При работе с Google Maps API для Android, координаты выдаются в величинах долготы и широты. Требуется перевести данные значения в метры. Есть ли какие нибудь библиотеки для этого, чтобы не изобретать велосипед? Пишу на Java.

Comment: Сколько метров будет 45° N 33° W?

Comment: 4985032.290487532, 6500000, если я ошибаюсь, поправьте меня

Comment: Интересно, спасибо. Возможно имеется ввиду что-то известное, но я, признаться, не понял как рассчитываются эти значения. Может поясните методику в тексте вопроса? Или ссылку на нее добавите?

Comment: Для перевода я воспользовался конвертером с [сайта](http://www.latlong.ru/sk.php). Еще есть ГОСТ 32453-2013.

Comment: Может отвечающим пригодится инфа с сайта: `Для получения плоских прямоугольных координат в принятой на территории Российской Федерации проекции Гаусса—Крюгера используют геодезические координаты на эллипсоиде Красовского...`

Comment: @Denis если вы знаете ГОСТ, тогда посмотрите там пункт `5.1.1 Преобразование геодезических координат в прямоугольные пространственные координаты осуществляют по формулам:`, там есть все формулы, которые нужны для такого преобразования...

Comment: @mit, да, можно сделать по госту, но вопрос заключается в том есть ли готовые библиотеки с уже реализованными функциями

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимый функционал оказался описан в классах [данного](https://github.com/Berico-Technologies/Geo-Coordinate-Conversion-Java) проекта. Для конвертации  из географической системы координат в UTM можно воспользоваться следующим кодом:

```
utmCoord = UTMCoord.fromLatLon(Angle.fromDegreesLatitude(latitude), Angle.fromDegreesLongitude(longitude));
```

Получим результат в виде: 41 N 371734.70589118626E 6293516.067325422N, где величины 371734.70589118626E 6293516.067325422N выражены в метрах.